# Вызвать метод из другого скрипта и из другой сцены без использования static в Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity3d, классы, static

Я кончено искал ответ на мой вопрос, но все решения были с применение static,а мне нужно без него и вот почему.
В одном скрипте на сцене1 есть метод1 который проставляет значения нужных полей.
В другом скрипте на сцене2 есть метод2 который должен вызвать метод1 и перейти на сцену1.
Вот скрин метода1.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как мне так сделать? Вызвать метод из другого скрипта и сцены без использования static, так как необходимо его отсутствие?

Comment: Используй [ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html), они вне сцен.

Comment: К ScriptableObject можно обращаться как к объекту и скрипту на нем?